# Jquery export JSON to CSV IE download issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, internet-explorer

I am working on a solution that will download json file in to csv format.

In Chrome, I am able to download file without any issue. But when I perform same task in IE, it refreshes the window and prints and goes back to its original window.

Here is my code:

```
var jsonData = [{
    "id": "1",
    "fname": "Ray",
    "lname" : "Mak",
    "Company" : "Microsoft"
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "fname": "Sam",
    "lname" : "Smith",
    "Company" : "Google"    
}];

function msieversion() {
  var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
  var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");
  if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./)) // If Internet Explorer, return true
  {
    return true;
  } else { // If another browser,
  return false;
  }
  return false;
}

function JSONToCSVConvertor(JSONData,fileName,ShowLabel) {
    var arrData = typeof JSONData != 'object' ? JSON.parse(JSONData) : JSONData;
    var CSV = '';
    if (ShowLabel) {
        var row = "";
        for (var index in arrData[0]) {
            row += index + ',';
        }
        row = row.slice(0, -1);
        CSV += row + '\r\n';
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < arrData.length; i++) {
        var row = "";
        for (var index in arrData[i]) {
            var arrValue = arrData[i][index] == null ? "" : '="' + arrData[i][index] + '"';
            row += arrValue + ',';
        }
        row.slice(0, row.length - 1);
        CSV += row + '\r\n';
    }
    if (CSV == '') {
        growl.error("Invalid data");
        return;
    }
    var fileName = "Result";
    if(msieversion()){
        var IEwindow = window.open();
        IEwindow.document.write('sep=,\r\n' + CSV);
        IEwindow.document.close();
        IEwindow.document.execCommand('SaveAs', true, fileName + ".csv");
        IEwindow.close();
    } else {
        var uri = 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,' + escape(CSV);
        var link = document.createElement("a");
        link.href = uri;
        link.style = "visibility:hidden";
        link.download = fileName + ".csv";
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
        document.body.removeChild(link);
    }
}
JSONToCSVConvertor(jsonData,"Results", true);
```

Here is my JSFiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/kocc33aw/).

Comment: Try using the solution suggested in past post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665115/create-a-file-in-memory-for-user-to-download-not-through-server)